# Google motion chart initial state - set time unit for slider

Tags: google-visualization

I am working with a **Google Motion Chart** with has a play button and slider at the bottom that animates the chart. I would like to set the time unit/steps used by the slider. The default seems to be a day ("D").

My drawChart method sets the initial state and I tried setting the timeUnit to "M" -  **"duration":{"multiplier":1,"timeUnit":"M"}** - for month but this did not change anything. I could not find any documentation on possible settings for the initial state variables.

Below is my method which sets the state:

```
function drawChart(data) {
        var evalObj = eval("(" + data + ")");
        var dataTbl = new google.visualization.DataTable(evalObj);
        var motionchart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
        var options = {};
        options['state'] =
        '{"iconKeySettings":[],"stateVersion":3,"time":"notime","xAxisOption":"_NOTHING","playDuration":15,
"iconType":"BUBBLE","sizeOption":"_UNISIZE","xZoomedDataMin":null,
"xZoomedIn":false, "duration":{"multiplier":1,"timeUnit":"M"},"yZoomedDataMin":null,"xLambda":1,"colorOption":"_UNIQUE_COLOR",
"nonSelectedAlpha":0.4,"dimensions":{"iconDimensions":   []},"yZoomedIn":false,"yAxisOption":"_NOTHING","yLambda":1,"yZoomedDataMax":null,
"showTrails":false,"xZoomedDataMax":null};';
        options['width'] = 800;
        options['height'] = 400;
        motionchart.draw(dataTbl, options);
    }
```

Is "M" the setting for month? How do I change the slider to use months instead of days for its steps?

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart#Configuration_Options) says:

> The second column must contain time values. Time can be expressed in any of the following formats:
>
> - Year - Column type: 'number'. Example: 2008.
> - Month, day and year - Column type: 'date'; values should be javascript Date instances.
> - Week number- Column type: 'string'; values should use the pattern YYYYWww, which conforms to ISO 8601. Example: '2008W03'.
> - Quarter - Column type: 'string'; the values should have the pattern YYYYQq, which conforms to ISO 8601. Example: '2008Q3'.

Reading another [thread](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=54), it looks like Google is throwing this in the trash and are not going to be enhancing the time units.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You can specify that the motion chart start with a specific state: that is, a set of selected entities and view customizations. To do this, you'll need to **first create** and display the chart, then make any state changes that you want the chart to show (select values, change settings, etc), then **export these settings** as a string, and finally use this string in your code, assigning it to the "state" option. The next two sections describe how to export and then use the state code.

1. Open a working chart and set the settings that you'd like to capture. Settings you can specify include opacity levels, zooming, and log vs linear scaling.
2. Open the Settings panel by clicking the wrench symbol in the lower right corner of the chart.
3. Click the Advanced link in the lower left corner to add the Advanced panel to the set.
4. Expand the Advanced panel and copy the contents of the State text box to your clipboard. (Note: instead of using the menu, described in steps 2—4, you could insert a button on your page that calls getState() and displays the current state in a message box.)
5. Assign the state string that you copied in the previous step to the "state" options parameter in your code, as shown here. When passed into the draw() method, the chart will be initialized to the state specified on startup.